# Send a textbox value to another

Tags: javascript, node.js, html

I've my html as below.

```
<input type="text" id="a" value="hello">
<input type="text" id="b">
<input type="button" value="click me" onClick="sendData()">
```

And to send the data in `a` to `b`, I use the below js.

```
function sendData() {
 document.getElementById('b').value =document.getElementById('a').value
 }
```

Now my requirement is I want to do the same in node js. Ice seen a couple of tutorials online but no where I've seen Dom manipulation of elements. Can someone please let me how can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Node is server - it does not have access to the DOM. It can add code to the text when sending <input value="value here" />

Comment: Node.js isn't a browser. It doesn't typically render webpages. It doesn't typically use DOM. Are you using modules which supply those features? It isn't clear what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: Hello, NodeJS is a server side framework. TextBoxes live at the client (in a browser environment). How is possible that you want? DOM manipulation is meaningless at the server.